# Trying to change JLabel using MouseEvent

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, mouselistener

my assignment is to change a jlabel by clicking on the label, but we haven't gotten into mouse adapters and mouse handling yet, we've only gone over overriding the 5 mouse events so that's all we can use. Heres what i have so far, but all it does is change the font of my name, i want it to also change the color of the JLabel to red when i click on my name.

```
class FontFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
JButton FirstFont;
JButton SecondFont;
JLabel myName;

public FontFrame(){
setSize(600, 200);
setLocation(300, 200);
Container contentpane = getContentPane();
myName = new JLabel("Aly");
FirstFont = new JButton("Chalkboard 14");
SecondFont = new JButton("Harrington 18");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(FirstFont);
panel.add(SecondFont);
panel.add(myName);
FirstFont.addActionListener(this);
SecondFont.addActionListener(this);
contentpane.add(panel, "Center");
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
Object source = e.getSource();
Font f1 = new Font("Chalkboard", Font.PLAIN, 14);
Font f2 = new Font("Harrington", Font.PLAIN, 18);
if(source == FirstFont){
    myName.setFont(f1);
}
else if(source == SecondFont){
        myName.setFont(f2);
    }
}
}

class mouseFrame extends FontFrame implements MouseListener{

public mouseFrame(){
    addMouseListener(this);
    myName.addMouseListener(this);
    FirstFont.addMouseListener(this);
    SecondFont.addMouseListener(this);
    add(myName);
    add(FirstFont);
    add(SecondFont);
    Container contentpane = getContentPane();
    contentpane.add(new FontFrame());
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    int fontbutton = e.getButton();
    if(fontbutton == MouseEvent.BUTTON1 ){
        myName.setForeground(Color.red);
    }
}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}

public class ChangeFont {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new FontFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You never actually create or show an instance of `MouseFrame`
2. `MouseFrame` doesn't call the `FontFrame`'s constructor (`super()`), but instead tries to add a new instance of `FontFrame` to it, which is an illegal operation

Start by changing `MouseFrame` so it calls the `super` constructor and only adds the `MouseListener` to the `JLabel`

```
public static class MouseFrame extends FontFrame implements MouseListener {

    public MouseFrame() {
        super();
        myName.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("...");
        int fontbutton = e.getButton();
        if (fontbutton == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            myName.setForeground(Color.red);
        }
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

}
```

Next, in the `main` method, create an instance of `MouseFrame`...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new MouseFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i did exactly what you said and it worked out flawlessly! i really appreciate the help :)